# Can't delete old kernel thus can't update and upgrade

Tags: kernel, dpkg

suggestions from other similar topics doesn't work

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  cloud-init linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  git git-man intel-microcode libpcap0.8 libsqlite3-0 linux-libc-dev python3-psutil
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 7,714 kB of archives.
After this operation, 304 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 intel-microcode amd64 3.20191115.1ubuntu0.16.04.2 [2,408 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.11.0-1ubuntu1.3 [397 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpcap0.8 amd64 1.7.4-2ubuntu0.1 [117 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.7 [736 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.7 [3,160 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-170.199 [839 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python3-psutil amd64 3.4.2-1ubuntu0.1 [55.7 kB]
Fetched 7,714 kB in 1s (6,164 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 106213 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic (3.13.0-85.129) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-85-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-85-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-85-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-85-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-85-generic
E: amd64-microcode: unsupported kernel version!
W: plymouth module (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//ubuntu-text.so) missing, skipping that theme.
sync: invalid option -- 'f'
Try 'sync --help' for more information.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic (3.13.0-86.131) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-86-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-86-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-86-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-86-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-86-generic
E: amd64-microcode: unsupported kernel version!
W: plymouth module (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//ubuntu-text.so) missing, skipping that theme.
sync: invalid option -- 'f'
Try 'sync --help' for more information.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```
````

Comment: Did you install or try to install a kernel different from the one your OS version expects?

Comment: nope, there was update from 14 to 16 month ago

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Comment: What command generated this output? eg `sudo apt autoremove`?

Comment: its apt-get upgrade, `sudo apt autoremove` has this https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49261561506_c845f98066_o.png

Comment: This problem looks very old. At least a year ago on 14.04, judging by the version numbers. Such problems get harder to fix with time, as you have surely discovered. To fix it, I see two options: You can pull the old 14.04 version of the amd64-microcode package and see if it will install long enough to uninstall those old kernels (unlikely). Or you can Nuke the old kernels with dpkg's `--force-remove-reinstreq` and spend a nice afternoon cleaning out all the files by hand (tedious). Or you can backup and reinstall (likely fastest and easiest)

Comment: How do you figure out that it's a year old? i could install packages a month ago and suddenly when i wanted to install new it failed with errors above

Comment: Did you tried to purge problematic `amd64-microcode` package with `sudo apt-get purge amd64-microcode`?